# How can I auto adjust a equation to appear in the entire page? (Scale to equations, is this exist?)

Tags: math-mode, spacing, equations, formatting, width

If I have a document like this:

```
\documentclass[landscape, 12pt]{report}

\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}

\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, graphics, setspace}
\newcommand{\mathsym}[1]{{}}
\newcommand{\unicode}[1]{{}}
\newcounter{mathematicapage}

\begin{document}    \begin{equation}\label{Equation:Naive_Bayes_Classifier}
    P\left(H_h|E_1,E_2,\ldots ,E_e,\ldots    E_{\mathbb{E}}\right)=\frac{P\left(H_h\right) P\left(E_1|H_h\right)    P\left(E_2|H_h,E_1\right) \text{$\ldots $P}
    \left(E_e|H_h,E_1,E_2,\ldots ,E_{e-1},E_{e+1} \ldots, E_{\mathbb{E}}\right) \text{$\ldots    $P}
    \left(E_{\mathbb{E}}|H_h,E_1,E_2,\ldots ,E_{\mathbb{E}-1}\right)}{ P\left(E_1,E_2,\ldots,E_e, \ldots    ,E_{\mathbb{E}}\right)}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

How can I auto adjust this equation to appear in the entire page, using all horizontal space? (Without badboxes or smaller than the width of the page?)

If is there a kind of scale to use in equations, giving explicity how greater the equation should become, this solver my problem too.

Comment: I added a `}{` to get your code to work- let me know if it wasn't appropriate (or simply roll back or edit)

Comment: You may also consider adjusting the equation layout (and not merely using `\frac`) in order to make it fit within `\textwidth`.

Comment: Why those useless `\left` and `\right`? And `\text{$\ldots$ P}` doesn't make much sense. If you want an upright `P` it should be `\mathrm{P}` in all the formula.

Comment: The equation was generated in *Mathematica*, which makes a ton of warts like that.

Comment: @rdhs is correct.

Comment: Looks like this is a difficult problem...

Comment: Now along with Hooked solution, you could also use the landscape package, to turn the page 90^0. Then you could increase the formula even more

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To "scale" an equation to fit a box you can use `\resizebox` from the package `graphicx`. Below is a stripped example of your code that does what you are looking for.

```
\documentclass[landscape, 12pt]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\noindent Here is some text
\begin{equation}
\resizebox{.9 \textwidth}{!} 
{
    $ a + b $
}
\end{equation}
and here is some more.
\end{document}
```

Here the `.9` determines how much of the width you'd like to take up, in this case I choose 90% though you can fit to your liking. The `!` as the second argument will preserve the aspect ratio.

Giving credit where it is due, a very similar question was [answered on Stack Exchange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106587/scale-an-equation-to-fit-exact-page-width) recently about *shrinking* the equation. In both cases the `\resizebox` should suffice, though it is not recommended. Personally, I would consider splitting the equation. Having an inconsistent math font size can be a typographical nightmare.

**Examples**

Here the argument to `\resizebox` is set to `1.0 \textwidth` (compiled with `pdflatex`):

[image: Example 1]

In this example it is set to `0.2 \textwidth`

[image: Example 2]

Comment: Your solution looks like a good one. But I tried implement it in kile and the `a+b` have the same size, even changing the `.9` to `.1`, `.99`, `5.5`. What's going on?

Comment: @GarouDan Hard to tell without seeing what you are seeing. I've added a picture so you can see what the final result looks like, I've slightly modified the code by adding some outside text so you can get a feel for how the equation scales.

Comment: This is very strange. Using this [code](http://pastebin.com/arnYZQAD) I got this [image](http://dug.im/a8b4c) outup in my dvi. I'm using kile and using ubuntu 10.04 lts =// if helps.

Comment: @GarouDan try compiling it with `pdflatex` from the command line, that's how the examples above were produced.

Comment: lol @Hooked. Using pdf (pdflatex) works (I usually never uses pdf, sorry). Why not with dvi (I use latex and then see the dvi)? Thanks, I think this ends the question.

Comment: @GarouDan To be honest, I'm not as savvy as other users here that could differentiate what happens from `pdflatex` to plain `latex`. It may be worth asking as a separate question. If you do that, provide a link here so that other can follow!

Answer (score 7):

Package `resizegather` can automatically shrink equations of environment `gather` of package `amsmath` to fit the line width.

The following example compares the equation using `\textstyle` of [rdhs' answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/35561/16967) with resizing the overlarge equation (too large by 148.64104pt):

```
\documentclass[landscape, 12pt]{report}
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\usepackage{resizegather}

\begin{document}
\begin{gather}
  \label{eq-tfrac}
    P\left(H_h|E_1,E_2,\ldots ,E_e,\ldots    E_{\mathbb{E}}\right)=\tfrac{P\left(H_h\right) P\left(E_1|H_h\right)    P\left(E_2|H_h,E_1\right) \text{$\ldots $P}
    \left(E_e|H_h,E_1,E_2,\ldots ,E_{e-1},E_{e+1} \ldots, E_{\mathbb{E}}\right) \text{$\ldots    $P}
    \left(E_{\mathbb{E}}|H_h,E_1,E_2,\ldots ,E_{\mathbb{E}-1}\right)}{ P\left(E_1,E_2,\ldots,E_e, \ldots    ,E_{\mathbb{E}}\right)}
  \\\label{eq-resized}
    P\left(H_h|E_1,E_2,\ldots ,E_e,\ldots    E_{\mathbb{E}}\right)=\frac{P\left(H_h\right) P\left(E_1|H_h\right)    P\left(E_2|H_h,E_1\right) \text{$\ldots $P}
    \left(E_e|H_h,E_1,E_2,\ldots ,E_{e-1},E_{e+1} \ldots, E_{\mathbb{E}}\right) \text{$\ldots    $P}
    \left(E_{\mathbb{E}}|H_h,E_1,E_2,\ldots ,E_{\mathbb{E}-1}\right)}{ P\left(E_1,E_2,\ldots,E_e, \ldots    ,E_{\mathbb{E}}\right)}
\end{gather}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

### Including the equation number on the same line

Two examles/variations:

```
\documentclass[landscape, 12pt]{report}
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\newcommand*{\Sample}{%
  P\left(H_h|E_1,E_2,\ldots ,E_e,\ldots
  E_{\mathbb{E}}\right)=\frac{P\left(H_h\right) P\left(E_1|H_h\right)
  P\left(E_2|H_h,E_1\right) \text{$\ldots $P}
  \left(E_e|H_h,E_1,E_2,\ldots ,E_{e-1},E_{e+1} \ldots,
  E_{\mathbb{E}}\right) \text{$\ldots    $P}
  \left(E_{\mathbb{E}}|H_h,E_1,E_2,\ldots ,
  E_{\mathbb{E}-1}\right)}{ P\left(E_1,E_2,\ldots,E_e, \ldots
  ,E_{\mathbb{E}}\right)}%
}

\begin{document}
\refstepcounter{equation}
\[
  \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{$\displaystyle\Sample$\quad(\theequation)}
\]
%
\refstepcounter{equation}
\[
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}X@{\quad}l@{}}
    \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{$\displaystyle\Sample$}&(\theequation)
  \end{tabularx}
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

**Note:** Keep in mind that it is usually better to avoid shrunk oversized equations.

Comment: Brilliant solution. I was looking for something like this for long time. Thanks

Comment: Is it possible to force the numbering to be on the right side (1st equation) instead of at the bottom (2nd equation)? I am trying to use `gather` with multiple large equations and would prefer to have the number on the right side even if the equations would become a little smaller.

Comment: @GuilhermeSalomé See updated answer.

Comment: !!! Say goodbye to `footnotesize` forever! XD

Answer (score 6):

Breaking huge fractions certainly is tricky, and I don't think there exists an automated solution for that.

So first off, let's see how your formula looks like (examples in plain-format):

```
\input amssym.def
\def\P{{\rm P}}
\def\E{\Bbb E}
$$
  \P(H_h|E_1,E_2,\dots,E_e,\dots E_\E)
  = { \P(H_h) \P(E_1|H_h) \P(E_2|H_h,E_1) \dots
    \P(E_e|H_h,E_1,E_2,\dots,E_{e-1},E_{e+1}\dots,E_\E) \ldots
    \P(E_\E|H_h,E_1,E_2,\dots,E_\E-1)
    \over
    \P(E_1,E_2,\dots,E_e,\dots,E_\E) }
$$
```

[image]

Oh my, we ran out of paper!

Knuth gives an example in the TeXbook how you can break the formula (exercise 19.9), and applying that solution here isn't exactly straight-forward, for there is many ways to do the splitting. Let's start off with two-line split:

```
$$
  \P(H_h|E_1,E_2,\dots,E_e,\dots E_\E)
  = {\displaystyle{\P(H_h) \P(E_1|H_h) \P(E_2|H_h,E_1) \dots
    \P(E_e|H_h,E_1,E_2,\dots,E_{e-1},E_{e+1}\dots,E_\E) \ldots
    \atop
    \hfill\P(E_\E|H_h,E_1,E_2,\dots,E_\E-1) } \over
      \P(E_1,E_2,\dots,E_e,\dots,E_\E) }
$$
```

[image]

Well, we didn't run out of paper, but we *were* left with an overfull box.

Maybe if we introduced a not-so-natural break instead:

```
$$
  \P(H_h|E_1,E_2,\dots,E_e,\dots E_\E)
  = { \displaystyle{ \P(H_h) \P(E_1|H_h) \P(E_2|H_h,E_1) \dots
    \P(E_e|H_h,E_1,E_2,
    \hfill
    \atop
    \qquad \dots,E_{e-1},E_{e+1}\dots,E_\E) \ldots
    \P(E_\E|H_h,E_1,E_2,\dots,E_\E-1) }
    \over
    \P(E_1,E_2,\dots,E_e,\dots,E_\E) }
$$
```

[image]

Now the space-requirements are better, albeit with a cost.

You could go *really* over the board and split it into three lines:

```
$$
  \P(H_h|E_1,E_2,\dots,E_e,\dots E_\E)
  = { \displaystyle{
      \displaystyle{ \P(H_h) \P(E_1|H_h) \P(E_2|H_h,E_1) \dots \hfill
      \atop
      \qquad \P(E_e|H_h,E_1,E_2,\dots,E_{e-1},E_{e+1}\dots,E_\E) \ldots }
      \atop
      \hfill \P(E_\E|H_h,E_1,E_2,\dots,E_\E-1) }
    \over
    \P(E_1,E_2,\dots,E_e,\dots,E_\E) }
$$
```

[image]

But that might be a tad too funky. I dunno.

So, how would an automated solution choose? I guess it would be really tricky.

Comment: Another option is to set the RHS as `\frac {1}{P(E_1,...E_{E}} \Big[ P(H_h) ... \Big]`. Then the term in the brackets can be split into multiple lines using `aligned` or `multlined`.

Comment: Not sure how much this matters, but you may want to replace `E_\E-1` with `E_{\E-1}` (towards the very end of the long numerator expressions) in the various examples you provide.

Answer (score 3):

You could make the fraction smaller using `\textstyle`:

```
\begin{equation}
  P(H_h|E_1,E_2,\ldots ,E_e,\ldots E_{\mathbb{E}})
  =\textstyle\frac{P(H_h) P(E_1|H_h)
  P(E_2|H_h,E_1) \text{$\ldots $P}
  (E_e|H_h,E_1,E_2,\ldots ,E_{e-1},E_{e+1} \ldots,E_{\mathbb{E}})\text{$\ldots$P}
  (E_{\mathbb{E}}|H_h,E_1,E_2,\ldots ,E_{\mathbb{E}-1})}
  { P(E_1,E_2,\ldots,E_e, \ldots ,E_{\mathbb{E}})}
\end{equation}
```

Or you could use `\\` within the `amsmath` environment `multline` to introduce a line-break:

```
\begin{multline}
  P(H_h|E_1,E_2,\ldots ,E_e,\ldots E_{\mathbb{E}})=\\
  \frac{P(H_h) P(E_1|H_h)
  P(E_2|H_h,E_1) \text{$\ldots $P}
  (E_e|H_h,E_1,E_2,\ldots ,E_{e-1},E_{e+1} \ldots,E_{\mathbb{E}})\text{$\ldots$P}
  (E_{\mathbb{E}}|H_h,E_1,E_2,\ldots ,E_{\mathbb{E}-1})}
  { P(E_1,E_2,\ldots,E_e, \ldots ,E_{\mathbb{E}})}
\end{multline}
```

Of course, it looks nicer with the equals sign on the same line as the fraction, but your margins are too big for that.

With the line-break moved, the equation becomes:

```
\begin{multline}
  P(H_h|E_1,E_2,\ldots ,E_e,\ldots E_{\mathbb{E}})\\
  =\frac{P(H_h) P(E_1|H_h)
  P(E_2|H_h,E_1) \text{$\ldots $P}
  (E_e|H_h,E_1,E_2,\ldots ,E_{e-1},E_{e+1} \ldots,E_{\mathbb{E}})\text{$\ldots$P}
  (E_{\mathbb{E}}|H_h,E_1,E_2,\ldots ,E_{\mathbb{E}-1})}
  { P(E_1,E_2,\ldots,E_e, \ldots ,E_{\mathbb{E}})}
\end{multline}
```

And then you can change the page margins using the `geometry` package options:

```
\usepackage[margin=1in,landscape]{geometry}
```

Comment: This is really helpfull @rdhs. Thanks so much. I need this this equations as large as possible to cut and use as a image in my presentation.

Comment: Unfortunally I need something more. Something like how change the size of a equation? Is there a scale to equations who I can explicity change the size in inches or points or cm's?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution using the `mathtools` package and its `\splitfrac` command; note that the `\splitfrac` directives may be nested. Overall, this solution looks very much like the third solution provided earlier by @morbusg. The advantage of the new solution may lie in its not having to use the TeX "primitive" command `\atop`.

Observe that there's no longer a need to typeset the formula in landscape mode. In addition, I've replaced some of the `\ldots` with `\cdots`, so as to better distinguish between items in a simple math list and items in a multiplicative list. Moreover, I've replaced the `|` vertical bars with `\mid` directives; the latter provide better horizontal spacing. Finally, I've gotten rid of the `\left` and `\right` directives, as they actually don't do anything in terms of resizing the parentheses in the present example.

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools, amssymb}

\begin{document} 
\begin{equation}\label{Equation:Naive_Bayes_Classifier}
P(H_h\mid E_1,E_2,\dots ,E_e,\dots E_{\mathbb{E}})=
\frac{\left( % place large parens around entire numerator expression
\splitfrac{P(H_h)\, P(E_1\mid H_h) \,
  P(E_2\mid H_h,E_1) \cdots }{
  \splitfrac{
    P(E_e\mid H_h,E_1,E_2,\dots ,E_{e-1},E_{e+1} \dots, 
      E_{\mathbb{E}}) \cdots }{
    P(E_{\mathbb{E}}\mid H_h,E_1,E_2,\dots,
      E_{\mathbb{E}-1})
  } % end of inner splitfrac
}   % end of outer splitfrac
\right)}
{ P(E_1,E_2,\dots,E_e,\dots,E_{\mathbb{E}})}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

If you want a bit more vertical whitespace between the three lines of the numerator expression, you could replace the `\splitfrac` directives with `\splitdfrac` instructions.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, your comment really clarifies what you want, and there's a better solution for that. (I'm not quite sure if it's appropriate to post a separate answer, but here goes.)

If you want *the page* to grow to fit *the equation*, then the best solution is to use the `standalone` document class and the `varwidth` package. You can also remove the equation numbering:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{varwidth}

\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, graphics, setspace}
\newcommand{\mathsym}[1]{{}}
\newcommand{\unicode}[1]{{}}
\newcounter{mathematicapage}

\begin{document}
\begin{varwidth}{50in}
\begin{equation*}
  P(H_h|E_1,E_2,\ldots ,E_e,\ldots E_{\mathbb{E}})
  =\frac{P(H_h) P(E_1|H_h)
  P(E_2|H_h,E_1) \text{$\ldots $P}
  (E_e|H_h,E_1,E_2,\ldots ,E_{e-1},E_{e+1} \ldots,E_{\mathbb{E}})\text{$\ldots$P}
  (E_{\mathbb{E}}|H_h,E_1,E_2,\ldots ,E_{\mathbb{E}-1})}
  { P(E_1,E_2,\ldots,E_e, \ldots ,E_{\mathbb{E}})}
\end{equation*}
\end{varwidth}
\end{document}
```

This gives a PDF file that can be converted directly to PNG and put into slides, no cropping required. You could probably get *Mathematica* to change its output like this automatically, but if not you could use `sed` to automate the substitutions.

Comment: When I tryed to run your code in Kile (Ubuntu 10.04 LTS) I got, `File 'standalone.cls' not found. \usepackage`. Where I can get this package (no result in google yet =/)?

Comment: Here's *a* `standalone.cls`: [tug.org](http://www.tug.org/texlive/Contents/live/texmf-dist/tex/latex/standalone/standalone.cls). And you can scale the page however you want. If you include it in another LaTeX doc (e.g., `beamer` slides), do something like `\includegraphics[width=8 in]{bigeqn.pdf}`. If you convert it to a PNG using GraphicsMagick, so something like `gm convert -monochrome -geometry 4800x -density 600 bigeqn.pdf bigeqn.png` (4800 = 8 in x 600 ppi).

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't solve the problem yet. Please see this code in [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/a5nsy4Q0). (I have installed standalone package)I tried several things but doesn't worked very well. Can you write a new code for me?

Comment: Thanks you so much. Now, with `Hooked` help (using pdf's instead dvi) I can see your idea works fine. Really thanks. If I could I'd like accept your solution as answer too. So, if someone like this solution as I please vote up. Cya.