# How to export an equation as an image without background?

Tags: math-mode, graphics, equations

For example, if we have a equation on a file like:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{varwidth}

\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, graphics, setspace}
\newcommand{\mathsym}[1]{{}}
\newcommand{\unicode}[1]{{}}
\newcounter{mathematicapage}

\begin{document}
   \begin{varwidth}{50in}
        \begin{equation*}
            P\left(H_h|E_e\right)=\frac{P\left(E_e|H_h\right)P\left(H_h\right)}{P\left(E_e\right)}
        \end{equation*}
    \end{varwidth}
\end{document}
```

How export it as a png image, without background? (Just the equation, without white background).

(I'd like a full comand to do this, compiling the .tex file and getting a png image as output)

I need this to generate equation images to a presentation.

Comment: A Suggestion: You migth want to prepare your presentation using `beamer` package and save yourself from the hassle :)

Comment: @percusse Unfortunally I need to use MSOffice apps to do this presentation. I'd like to learn beamer but now I can't. My advisor would like a MSOffice presentation =/ so I'm searching for a solution using equations without background...Anyway thanks about the suggestion.

Comment: Maybe this answer helps: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3/compiling-documents-online/1654#1654

Comment: @GarouDan: I corrected a typo in your MWE. It appears that you had what appears to be the same typo in [an earlier question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35554/how-can-i-auto-adjust-a-equation-to-appear-in-the-entire-page-scale-to-equatio), so please test your MWE before submitting them here.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use `convert` from from [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org):

```
pdflatex formula.tex
convert -density 300 formula.pdf -quality 90 formula.png
```

Here is the resulting PNG file:

[image]

This solutions is from [TeX to image over command line](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34054/tex-to-image-over-command-line/34058#34058), which you should see as this will allow you to specify the formula on the command line.

Comment: `convert --version`
`Version: ImageMagick 6.5.7-8 2010-12-02 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2009 ImageMagick Studio LLC
Features: OpenMP`

I tried `convert -transparent-color white -density 300 5.pdf -quality 90 5.png` and `convert -density 300 5.pdf -transparent-color white -quality 90 5.png`. But I got the same results... =/

Comment: Seems that you version is much older: `convert --version` yields:
`Version: ImageMagick 6.6.9-3 2011-04-04 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2011 ImageMagick Studio LLC
Features:    `. So perhaps try downloading the latest version.

Comment: @PeterGrill Thanks so much. I have installed the new ImageMagick and it works fine. Thx.

Comment: If you find yourself doing this sort of conversion via ImageMagick a lot, a very useful wrapper is [tex2im](http://www.nought.de/tex2im.php)

Comment: If you have an older version of ImageMagick, you may need to add the option `-transparent-color white` to also have a transparent background.

Answer (score 7):

The following works for me:

1. Compile to dvi using `latex` (not `pdflatex`!).

   By the way, you have a typo in your example: should be `P\left(H_h|E_e\right)=\frac{P\left(E_e|H_h\right)P\left(H_h\right)}{P\left(E_e\right)}`
2. Use `dvipng`:

   ```
   dvipng -bg transparent -o myfile.png myfile.dvi
   ```

Comment: this works fine. Thanks. But maybe, because of this [question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35554/how-can-i-auto-adjust-a-equation-to-appear-in-the-entire-page-scale-to-equatio) and this [discussion](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35698/why-using-pdf-we-get-better-results-than-using-dvi) I need to use pdflatex, can we use it? I tried PeterGrill solution but didn't worked, even inserting the `-transparent-color white` as you said.

Comment: You are right: `-transparent-color` does not work.  It seems newer version of `convert` understand `-alpha transparent`, but mine, unfortunately, does not.  There are other methods listed here: http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/masking/, but neither works for me :(

Comment: @Looks like in this link we cant convert a white background in a transparent one. I tried several thing as there explain but nothing works. Have you had sucess? (Tried this -alpha transparent too)

Answer (score 5):

> I need this to generate equation images to a presentation.

I use an [online latex equation editor](https://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php).

It has a rich user interface that helps writing the equation and it renders in real time. Use the export menu to download the image as an svg, png, pdf or gif formats. It provides the code to embed the equation in HTML and others. I can also create a link that will show your equation, here is [your equation](https://latex.codecogs.com/gif.image?%5Cdpi%7B500%7D&space;P%5Cleft(H_h%7CE_e%5Cright)=%5Cfrac%7BP%5Cleft(E_e%7CH_h%5Cright)P%5Cleft(H_h%5Cright)%7D%7BP%5Cleft(E_e%5Cright)%7D).

Comment: This might not be the best, but it's a valid answer to the question. I don't understand the down vote.

Answer (score 2):

I use [mathurl](http://mathurl.com)

it'll allow you to save your equations as .png

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: The resolution is poor...