# \eqalignno compiling question in MiKTeX

Tags: align

I'm a `TeX`/`LaTeX` newbie. I would like to generate a .png using `dvipng` for the below equation.

```
$$\eqalignno{\overline {Z_{w,h}^{(LDGM)}} =&amp;\sum\limits _{e=0}^{t} \left [{{ 1}\over { t\choose e}} {\rm coef}\left (\prod _{u=1}^{\infty} (1 + x^{u}y)^{m {\mathtilde {\lambda }}_{u}}, x^{e}y^{w}\right)\right. \cr &amp; \left . \times {\rm coef} \!\left (\prod _{v=1}^{\infty} [f_{-}(x,v)y \!+\! f_{+}(x,v)]^{n {\mathtilde {\rho }}_{v}}, x^{e}y^{h} \!\right)\!\right]\!. \cr &amp;&amp;{\hbox{(3)}}}$$
```

Please suggest what is wrong with the equation and how to generate a dvi for this.

Comment: What is the error message you get? What command line are you using to generate the output file?  Also, best if you  post a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass`.

Comment: As far as generating a `.png` file see [How to export a equation as a image without background?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35690/how-to-export-a-equation-as-a-image-without-background/35696#35696), and [TeX to image over command line](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34054/tex-to-image-over-command-line/).

Comment: @PeterGrill: Possibly no `documentclass`. This seems more like Plain TeX to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The TeX source looks like plain TeX code because of the `\eqalignno` command. If you just want to fix it, replace the `&amp;` XML entities with plain `&` characters. Also, `\mathtilde` is not available in plain TeX. Thus, you can either use `\tilde` instead, or define a macro that simply maps `\mathtilde` to `\tilde`. The resulting document looks something like this:

```
\def\mathtilde{\tilde}
$$
   \eqalignno{\overline {Z_{w,h}^{(LDGM)}} =
   & \sum\limits _{e=0}^{t} \left [{{1}\over {t\choose e}} {\rm coef}
     \left(\prod _{u=1}^{\infty} (1 + x^{u}y)^{m {\mathtilde {\lambda }}_{u}},
     x^{e}y^{w}\right)\right. \cr 
   & \left . \times {\rm coef} \! \left(\prod_{v=1}^{\infty} 
     [f_{-}(x,v)y \!+\! f_{+}(x,v)]^{n{\mathtilde{\rho}}_{v}}, 
     x^{e}y^{h} \!\right)\!\right]\!. \cr 
   &
   & \hbox{(3)}}
$$
\bye
```

To get a DVI file, compile it with `tex <filename>`.

[image]