# Error-Undefined control sequence

Tags: errors

I occurred a problem recently, but, I　donot know how to solve it?

Error:

```
Undefined control sequence.
l.26 $$\eqalignno
                 {P^{-1}&=P_{1}^{-1}+P_{2}^{-1}\cr P^{-1}\mathhat{x}&=P_{1}^...
```

My codes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
 $$\eqalignno{P^{-1}&=P_{1}^{-1}+P_{2}^{-1}\cr P^{-1}\mathhat{x}&=P_{1}^{-1}\mathhat{x}_{1}+P_{2}^{-1}\mathhat{x}_{2}.&\hbox{(7)}}$$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this you want?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
 \begin{align}
 \begin{aligned}
 P^{-1}           &=P_{1}^{-1}+P_{2}^{-1}\\
 P^{-1}\hat{x}&=P_{1}^{-1}\hat{x}_{1}+P_{2}^{-1}\hat{x}_{2}%.(7)
 \end{aligned}
 \end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Actually, I should admit that I don't understand your code (`\eqalignno` and `\mathhat`). And in latex, don't use `$$`.

Comment: `\eqalignno` is macro from plainTeX, but `\mathhat` is unknown. The construction looks like plain TeX and the first three lines and the last line of OP's code is only something like curiosity.

Comment: Yes, thank you,  you solved my problems. It seems I mix the `Tex ` codes with `Latex` environment, see this, http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/55694/44227.

Comment: @wipet You are right, actually, I copy this code  from `TEX Source` of  an IEEE paper which is a `Full Text in HTML` version in order to be used in my paper.