# How to make a rich png image from a Latex Math Equation

Tags: tex-core, dvi

I have a `LaTeX` math equation that I have been trying to convert it into a rich `.png` image by compiling the `.tex` file into `.dvi` and then from `.dvi` to `.png`. But I noticed that the Image is small and the background of the image is dark. Below is my code:

```
\documentclass[30pt]{article}
\DeclareMathSizes{30}{30}{30}{30}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\begin{displaymath}
\int\frac{d\theta}{1+\theta^2} = \tan^{-1}\theta+ C
\end{displaymath}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436). Does [How to export a equation as a image without background?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35690/how-to-export-a-equation-as-a-image-without-background) answer your question?  If so we can close this question as a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my script, maybe it will be useful for you:

```
#!/bin/sh
prefix="tmp_$$"
if [ "$1" = "" ]; then
    echo -e "\nUsage: $(basename $0) \"latex string\" [output filename]\n"
    exit
fi
[ "$2" != "" ] && output="$2" || output=$(date +%y.%m.%d_%H:%M:%S.png)
tex="$prefix.tex"
cat > $tex << EOF
\documentclass[12pt]{minimal}
\usepackage[koi8-r]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\usepackage[intlimits]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\pagestyle{empty}
\parindent=0pt
\setbox0=\hbox{
EOF
echo $1 >> $tex
cat >> $tex << EOF
}
\textheight=\ht0
\textwidth=\wd0
\oddsidemargin=-1cm
\topmargin=-1.5cm
\advance\textheight by 1cm
\advance\textwidth by 1cm
\begin{document}
\vbox{\vss\hbox{\hss\copy0\hss}\vss}
\end{document}
EOF
latex $tex
dvipng -D 600 $prefix.dvi -o $output
rm -f $prefix*
```

It generates png files from command line.