# How to load LaTeX libraries in latex2png

Tags: latex-2-png

I'm not sure whether this question is completely within the scope of TeX.SE (because it is actually related to a special website which uses TeX), but as some users may have some experience to work with, I'm gonna bring it up here:

You've probably heard of [latex2png](http://latex2png.com/) website. I often use it when I need some labels for my figures generated by other software except LaTeX (e.g. Adobe Illustrator). My current requirement is generation of a label like this:

[image]

In LaTeX, it's a piece a cake by means of:

```
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
```

then,

```
\mathscr{C}_{\hat{x}}
```

As I need to generate it in `latex2png`, it doesn't use `mathrsfs` by default. So, its output is something like this:

[image]

which is completely different compared to what I need. I'd just tried to add `\usepackage{mathrsfs}` before `\mathscr{C}_{\hat{x}}`, but the dull thing doesn't understand it.

Do you know any approach to do this by `latex2png` or some other tool?

Comment: you'd have to ask on that site, it looks like it just sets a single math expression so no chance to load fonts really.  but if you have latex installed why not just make the pngs locally?

Comment: Something like this? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35690/how-to-export-a-equation-as-a-image-without-background

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Yes, but I am a lazy engineer, always looking for the shortest and easiest path to what I need! This website did sound to be "VERY" useful, as seemingly, it isn't...

Comment: @TorbjørnT.: I think so... Thanks... I'm gonna give it a try...

Comment: I can see it's useful if you haven't got tex locally but if you have I can't see how it can be more convenient, I post a latex generated png for almost every answer I post and it would be a real pain if you had to go to an external website every time

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: You're right... I need to reconsider my viewpoint...

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I guess if you are working in another application .... Though I don't see how the web can be *more* convenient.

Comment: @cfr: When one does something with `just a couple of clicks (instead of coding and compilation)`, it might be interpreted as `more convenient`. As you are all LaTeX heros, coding might be more convenient for you, considerably! :D

Comment: you have to type the expression either way so then for most people it's just a matter of some clicks in their web interface or a click in your editor, not much difference is there?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: As a non-professional user, looking for required packages, required commands, etc. might be more cumbersome that those sort of clicks. But roughly, I do agree with you.

Comment: er.. but... your question is exactly how to add \requirepackge call to the web interface:-) so that would be the same (if it were available) and the commands to use in the actual expression are the same.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: They are not the same, if you notice. :) for instance, if we consider the link shared by Torbjorn, the answer suggested to use `convert` command from command line. At least one requires some time to master it and get rid of potential errors within her tries. So, that web interface can sometimes be helpful not to face with some complexities.

Comment: you only need to sort out the convert call once and stick it on a button in your editor, it's no different from having an editor button that does latex latex bibtex latex dvips ps2pdf, also for one off I  don't do that at all I just view in my pdf viewer and just clip a rectange fromthe screen and save as pdf

Comment: I've never used `convert` just to make a PNG either. Select selection tool -> select rectangle -> secondary click -> name file. I don't do this in my editor at all, but in the viewer.