# How create a paper of x,y dimensions size?

Tags: paper-size, standalone

How can I create a paper of A1 size on latex? Or a x,y (in centimeters) dimensions paper?

In \documentclass looks like there isn't this option. I need use the `\documentclass{standalone}` package too (to print out some formulas).

I would like create a paper with dimensions of x and y centimeters. Could be a paper of A1 size ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paper_size)) too, I think will works fine to me.

I have fond this [link](http://nxg.me.uk/docs/posters/) but I can't change the `\documentclass`.

**For other users interested**

How to generate a standalone equation (formula) using latex without background and with a specified dimension?

With these code below (Bayes_theorem.tex)

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage[left=0cm,top=0cm,right=0cm,nohead,nofoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, graphics, setspace}
\newcommand{\mathsym}[1]{{}}
\newcommand{\unicode}[1]{{}}
\newcounter{mathematicapage}

\geometry{
paperwidth=12cm,
paperheight=30cm,
margin=0cm
}
\begin{document}\sloppy
\begin{equation*}
\resizebox{1.0 \textwidth}{!} 
{
$
  P\left(H_h|E_e\right)=\frac{P\left(E_e|H_h\right)P\left(H_h\right)}{P\left(E_e\right)}
$
}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

, run:

> $pdflatex Bayes_theorem.tex

then

> $convert -geometry 4800x -density 4000 Bayes_theorem.pdf -quality 90 Bayes_theorem.png

And this beatifull formula without background will appear:

[image: Bayes_theorem]

This was possible with the help of several community users helping me in this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35753/how-create-a-paper-of-x-y-dimensions-size) itself and these others [1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35690/how-to-export-a-equation-as-a-image-without-background), [2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35554/how-can-i-auto-adjust-a-equation-to-appear-in-the-entire-page-scale-to-equatio).

Thanks so much.

Comment: Have a look at the geometry package.

Comment: Do you want to create a poster? If so, there is the related question [How to create posters using LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/341/how-to-create-posters-using-latex)

Comment: `standalone` can be used as a documentclass or as a package, the differences are explained in the [documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/standalone/standalone.pdf). I am not sure what you want here

Comment: I don't understand... Why not just use `standalone` and tell whatever software you print with to scale it to fill A0? LaTeX gives vector output, so only the *proportions* matter. The output could be the same once printed. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use [the `geometry` package](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/geometry/):

[image]

### Notes:

- `\sloppy` used to loosen the spacing requirements to work for a smaller width without overflowing into margin. Should not be needed in your actual document. See [Why is text being placed beyond the specified line width?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18210/why-is-text-being-placed-beyond-the-specified-line-width/18236#18236)
- `[showframe]` option used to display the margins
- To see the layout also try `\usepackage{layout}` and add `\layout` after the `begin{document}`.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\geometry{
paperwidth=6cm,
paperheight=4cm,
margin=0.5cm
}
\begin{document}\sloppy
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Comment: This works very fine with `standalone`. Really thx.

Answer (score 5):

```
\usepackage[a1paper]{geometry}
```

is possible with a current `geometry` package.