# Setting a single equation in a paragraph in a smaller font

Tags: equations, fontsize, paragraphs

I'm trying to figure out the best way of making a single equation just a little bit smaller.  Of course, I could try and break up the equation into pieces and proceed that way, but I'd like to understand the best way to accomplish this task.  Here's the problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Here is a bunch of text that I'm writing for no good reason. 
The overall purpose is to demonstrate how to make an equation 
set in a different font size from the surrounding paragraph
without messing up the spacing, like we do here:
{\footnotesize \[ f(x) = g(x) \] }
with an equation set as \verb#{ \footnotesize \[  f(x) = g(x) \]}#
\end{document}
```

This results in a terribly scrunched looking paragraph, because the \footnotesize command changes the baseline, I believe.

How do I avoid this?

Comment: Why do you want to resize the equation. Changing the type size isn't considered good practice. Perhaps you can break the equation?

Comment: Let me add to Marc's comment the following observation: If you're pressed for space while typesetting a long displayed formula, rather than finding a way to set the entire formula in a smaller fontsize -- `\footnotesize` is roughly 20% (linearly) smaller than `\normalize`!, and is probably already pushing the limits of readability of anything but an utterly trivial formula -- you should consider decreasing the amount of whitespace inserted around operators of type `mathbin` (e.g., `+` and `-`) and `mathrel` (e.g., `=`). Small adjustments of these parameters won't harm legibility at all.

Comment: There are a lot of relevant suggestions [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35554/9092).

Answer (score 5):

Use the math fontsize commands `\scriptstyle`, `\scriptscriptstyle` ?

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Here is a bunch of text that I'm writing for no good reason. The overall
purpose is to demonstrate how to make an equation set in a different font size
from the surrounding paragraph without messing up the spacing, like we do here:
 \[\scriptstyle f(x) = g(x) \]  with an equation set as
\verb#{\footnotesize \[  f(x) = g(x) \]}#
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\scriptstyle` changes too many of the other spacing aspects.  Compare `\[ \scriptstyle \int_0^1 \sum_{i=1}^k f(x) = g(x) \]` to `\[ \int_0^1 \sum_{i=1}^k f(x) = g(x) \]`  The equal sign doesn't have enough space around it, the limits are in the wrong location, etc.

Answer (score 4):

This might work (still looks odd though)

```
\documentclass{article}
\parskip2\baselineskip

\begin{document}
\showoutput
Here is a bunch of text that I'm writing for no good reason. 
The overall purpose is to demonstrate how to make an equation 
set in a different font size from the surrounding paragraph
without messing up the spacing, like we do here:
\par\nobreak{\parskip0pt \footnotesize \noindent\[ f(x) = g(x) \]}%
with an equation set as \verb#{ \footnotesize \[  f(x) = g(x) \]}#

\end{document}
```

Comment: please add `\nobreak` after `\par` so there can't be a page break just before the display.  (if you put `\vspace*{39pc}` at the top instead of `\showoutput` you'll see what i mean.)  tsk.

Comment: This one seems to work a little a little bit better: `\par\nobreak{\parskip0pt \noindent \parbox{\linewidth}{\footnotesize \[ f(x) = g(x) \]}}`

Answer (score 4):

For a single equation without one can do with

```
\[
\mbox{\small$\displaystyle
long equation
$}
\]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `adjustbox` package. You can have it scale your equation so that it just fits into the `\textwidth`.

```
\begin{adjustbox}{width=\textwidth,totalheight=\textheight,keepaspectratio}
%Equation goes here.
\end{adjustbox}
```

Answer (score 2):

rather than changing the font size, you might consider using `\scalebox` from the `graphicx` package.  in this example, the scaling factor is ridiculously small to demonstrate that the baseline spacing isn't fouled up.  however, unless you *really* must, shrinking displays is much less preferable than reformulating them (e.g., to use more lines) so they can be read easily.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
Here is a bunch of text that I'm writing for no good reason. 
The overall purpose is to demonstrate how to make an equation 
set in a different font size from the surrounding paragraph
without messing up the spacing, like we do here:
\[ \scalebox{.3}{$\displaystyle f(x) = g(x)$} \]
with an equation set as \verb#\[ \scalebox{.3}{$\displaystyle f(x) = g(x)$} \]#
\end{document}
```

[image: text with rescaled display]

Answer (score 1):

Changing font size and trying to fit a very long formula on one line is not going to benefit readability. However, there is a way to fit slightly more math in a line without changing font size: by sacrificing good spacing. Using @Mico's idea, we decrease the amount of space that TeX inserts between objects in math mode:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\[ x+y=5, x-y=1 \]

\begingroup
  \thinmuskip=1mu
  \medmuskip=2mu minus 2mu
  \thickmuskip=3mu
  \[ x+y=5, x-y=1 \]
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

[image]

The default definitions of the skips are

```
\thinmuskip=3mu
\medmuskip=4mu plus 2mu minus 4mu
\thickmuskip=5mu plus 5mu
```

I omitted the `plus` components because I do not expect the formula to stretch.