# Using an insert in smaller type in a paragraph without changing text line spacing

Tags: spacing, fontsize

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Setting a single equation in a paragraph in a smaller font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45354/setting-a-single-equation-in-a-paragraph-in-a-smaller-font)

I want to shrink the size of some typeset material inserted in the middle of a paragraph.  The following tex file produces the font sizes that I want, but the line spacing in the paragraph prior to `\begin{footnotesize}` is improperly altered.  Why is this happening?  How can I change the font size without changing the spacing of the surrounding text?

```
\documentclass{article}

% Commands to typeset code in a certain style
% Not relevant to the problem
\newcommand{\letE}{\mathbf{let}\;}
\newcommand{\inE}{\mathbf{in}\;}
\newcommand{\qlambda}[1]{\lambda#1\to}
\newcommand{\app}[1]{#1\;}
\newcommand{\putspace}{\mathord{}}
\newcommand{\name}[1]{\mathit{#1}}
\begin{document}

This is an example of a document where paragraph spacing is altered
because the size of some text in the paragraph is changed.

The following expression in the polymorphic lambda calculus is
rendered in a small font so that it can be displayed with fewer line breaks.
\begin{footnotesize}
\begin{tabbing}
$\letE \name{double} = \qlambda{f} \qlambda{x} \app f (\app fx)$ \\
$\inE\putspace$\=
  $\letE \name{twohundredfiftysix} = \putspace$\=%
    $\letE \name{four} = \app{\name{double}}\name{double}\;%
      \inE \app{\name{four}}\name{four}$ \\
\>$\inE \app{\name{twohundredfiftysix}}\name{twohundredfiftysix}$
\end{tabbing}
\end{footnotesize}
Vexingly, the use of \verb+footnotesize+ has altered the
spacing of the preceding lines in the same paragraph.

\end{document}
```

**Edit:** Changed to a non-math example.

Comment: agree with @DavidCarlisle's duplicate pointer, but the title text for this question is a bit clearer.  recommend combining.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks for finding that.  The answer here works better for my purposes though.  The answers on 45354 are more specific to math typesetting.

Comment: rather than voting to close, i recommend that the text of this question be modified so that the dependence is on something other than text.  a possible (and genuine) example is the need to set a block of verbatim code at a smaller size than the main text while remaining "within" a paragraph.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I put in a formatted code example to represent what I'm actually using it for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that the `footnotesize` environment still forms part of the previous paragraph. TeX actually assembles an entire paragraph before deciding on an optimized line breaking, leading to the `footnotesize` environment influence. Issue a formal `\par` and remove the spurious space before the next paragraph using `%` (if you want the paragraph components to be "joined"):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

This is an example of a document where paragraph spacing is altered
because the size of some text in the paragraph is changed.

The following long and complicated formula is rendered in a small font
so that it can be displayed with fewer line breaks.\par
\begin{footnotesize}
\[ x = 1 \]
\end{footnotesize}%
Vexingly, the use of \verb+footnotesize+ has altered the
spacing of the preceding lines in the same paragraph.

\end{document}​
```

Comment: `\footnotesize` is not an environment, but a command.

Comment: the problem with this solution is that the values for the skip above the display aren't applied the same when a paragraph break intervenes; also, a paragraph break permits a page break which isn't good practice.  packing the "smallified" material in a box and displaying the box avoids those problems.  but this is still essentially a duplicate of the question noted above, hence this comment instead of an answer.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: I agree that the request is out of the norm. My answer attempted to address the question "Why is it happening" and not how to generate something similar in a better way.

Comment: @Werner -- i applaud the "why is it happening?" approach.  unfortunately, it still looks to me like the same question. i'll make a suggestion to modify the text of this question to either remove the implied dependence on math, or explain that something other than math is responsible for the situation.